# How to fix OutOfBoundsException error? Please Explain

Tags: java, arrays

OOB Exception. How to debug?

```
        int sum[]= new int[4], ctr = 0, sums=0;
        for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++){
            int col = 0;
            for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
                sum[row] += x[row][column];
                sums += x[row][column];
                col += x[column][row];
            }
            ctr++;
            System.out.println("The sum of column " + ctr +": " + col);
            System.out.println("The sum of row " + ctr +": " + sum[row]);
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of all arrays: "+sums);

    }
}
```

This is the code. The problem lies within `col += x[column][row];`
I'm stuck, Please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
    sum[row] += x[row][column];
    sums += x[row][column];
    col += x[column][row];
}
```

You have more rows than you do columns.

So do this to catch it:

```
for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
    sum[row] += x[row][column];
    sums += x[row][column]

    if (row < x[row].length){
        col += x[column][row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! i get it now with the help of "Hence x[0][3] will give you OOB exception." from AJ. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your code

```
 System.out.println(column+" "+row);
 col += x[column][row];
```

After running your code.. at the end, `row` value becomes 3

Hence `x[0][3]` will give you OOB exception.

You have to handle `col += x[column][row];` in some condition so that it never gets executed if row exceeds the value 3

Comment: so how do i remove OOB exception? and please explain it further. bear with my ignorance. Thanks for the answer